# Changing linear-gradient with Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the linear gradient with JavaScript in my project. My problem is that after running the code nothing happens. If I try to use the linear-gradient string directly in my CSS class container, everything works fine but it doesn't work with changing it via JavaScript. Here's the code I'm trying to run:

```js
function init() {
    var Lohn = "undefined";
    var Datum = "undefined";
    var Pausenstueck = "undefined";
    var Zakstueck = "undefined";
    var Ueberstundenstueck = "undefined";
    var StundeKoord = "undefined";
    var Tagesdauer = "undefined";

    let UebersichtTemplate = document.createElement("dd");
    let UebersichtDD = document.getElementById("Uebersicht_Window_child");

    UebersichtTemplate.innerHTML = "<span class='textRight'>" + Lohn + "</span><span class='text'>" + Datum + "</span>";

    let a = document.importNode( UebersichtTemplate,true);
a.classList.add("percentage", "percentage-" + Math.round(StundeKoord*Tagesdauer));
    let colorString = "linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f " + Pausenstueck + Zakstueck + Ueberstundenstueck + " 100%);"
 UebersichtDD.appendChild(a);

    a.style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(to right,  #9c9e9f 0%,#9c9e9f 50%, #F53323 50%, #F53323 100%)';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Uebersicht_Window_child"></div>
 </body>
```

I already tried using double quotes instead of single quotes but it also doesn't work. leaving the "-webkit-" doesn't solve my problem either... I absolutely don't know the problem. Hope you guys could help me :)

Thank you!

Comment: You probably should try and turn this into an [mcve].  If people can't reproduce your issue they won't be able to help fix it, especially since problem is more about modifying styles than about linear gradients.  You're including a lot of variables that are undefined that this code depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one major issue: You never actually insert the `dd` element that you imported into the document:

From [Document​.import​Node()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode):

> The Document object's importNode() method creates a copy of a Node or
>   DocumentFragment from another document, *to be inserted into the
>   current document later*.

(Emphasis mine)

There are a couple of other issues, mainly around code structure and style - but they may not be pertinent to the core question - but also syntax problems with creating the colorString that may have been contributing.

```js
function init() {
    var Lohn        = "undefined";
    var Datum       = "undefined";
    var StundeKoord = "undefined";
    var Tagesdauer  = "undefined";
    // -----------------------------
    var Pausenstueck       = "#9c9e9f 50%";
    var Zakstueck          = "#F53323 50%";
    var Ueberstundenstueck = "#F53323 100%";

    let UebersichtTemplate = document.createElement("dd");
    UebersichtTemplate.innerHTML = "<span class='textRight'>" + Lohn + "</span>" +
                                   "<span class='text'>" + Datum + "</span>";
    let a = document.importNode( UebersichtTemplate, true );
    a.classList.add( "percentage", "percentage-" + Math.round(StundeKoord*Tagesdauer) );
    a.style.backgroundImage = `-webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #9c9e9f 0%, ${Pausenstueck}, ${Zakstueck}, ${Ueberstundenstueck} )`;
    // insert the imported node.
    document.body.appendChild(a);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="Uebersicht_Window_child"></div>
 </body>
```